# Why am I getting "Failed to start redpanda.service: Unit redpanda.service not found." while trying to install Redpanda?

Tags: apt, software-installation, services

I am getting below error while trying to install Redpanda

```
$ curl -1sLf 'https://packages.vectorized.io/nzc4ZYQK3WRGd9sy/redpanda/cfg/setup/bash.deb.sh' | sudo -E bash && sudo apt install redpanda -y && sudo systemctl start redpanda

Executing the  setup script for the 'vectorized/redpanda' repository ...

   OK: Checking for required executable 'curl' ...
   OK: Checking for required executable 'apt-get' ...
   OK: Detecting your OS distribution and release using system methods ...
 ^^^^: ... Detected/provided for your OS/distribution, version and architecture:
 >>>>:
 >>>>: ... distro=ubuntu  version=20.04  codename=focal  arch=x86_64  
 >>>>:
   OK: Checking for apt dependency 'apt-transport-https' ...
   OK: Checking for apt dependency 'ca-certificates' ...
   OK: Checking for apt dependency 'gnupg' ...
  RUN: Importing 'vectorized/redpanda' repository GPG key into   OK: Importing 'vectorized/redpanda' repository GPG key into apt ...
   OK: Checking if upstream install config is OK ...
   OK: Installing 'vectorized/redpanda' repository via apt ...
   OK: Updating apt repository metadata cache ...
   OK: The repository has been installed successfully - You're ready to rock!

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
redpanda is already the newest version (21.8.1-beta2-1-4dde38a2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
**Failed to start redpanda.service: Unit redpanda.service not found.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems `redpanda.service` is not found. Can you check your services, it may be named differently.

```
ls /lib/systemd/system | grep redpanda
```

Then start with the name you found. If you can't find the service, try reinstalling it.

- Remove it first.

```
sudo apt purge redpanda
```

- Install again, copy it directly to your terminal. (Source: https://vectorized.io/docs/quick-start-linux)

```
curl -1sLf 'https://packages.vectorized.io/nzc4ZYQK3WRGd9sy/redpanda/cfg/setup/bash.deb.sh' | sudo -E bash && \
sudo apt install redpanda -y && \
sudo systemctl start redpanda
```

If this one doesn't solve your problem either you should ask for help from `redpanda`. Or wait for someone has experience with `redpanda` here.